# What does "Two adults allow at least $35" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following [travel guide](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=VarTAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=Two%20adults%20allow%20at%20least%20%C2%A355&source=bl&ots=x-Wh_hU109&sig=ACfU3U3nTJPxsalBTCTFTuVamjeiXVKLlA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY44LAv7PgAhVxtosKHR6tDJcQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Two%20adults%20allow%20at%20least%20%C2%A355&f=false) I stumbled upon the following phrase:

> Art and shopping: **Two adults allow at least $35**

I can guess that it means that you should take at least $35 if you go to the place or that it's an average minimum for shopping at the place.

But the question is that I don't understand wording of the pharse. Who allow what? Does it have the special meaning which I don't know?

Comment: It should read: “FOR two adults, allow at least $35”. In its current form without the “for”, it’s grammatically and logically incorrect.

Comment: A colon or dash would also help: 
Art and shopping: Two adults - allow at least $35

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When it comes to signage, alerts, advisory notes etc, certain rules of grammar are ignored. This is the case in most languages and cultures.

"Allow" in this context means *to budget for* an average or expected amount of money.

If it were to be explained grammatically it would probably say:

> You should allow for a minimum spend of $35 per two adults.

It is abbreviated because it is in place of a cost. If something had a very specific price, rather than an estimate like this, you would expect to see something like:

> Tickets - $35

... which we understand means "*tickets cost $35 each*".

Comment: Thanks, the "allow for" phrasal verb is what I was looking for.